# Thumbnails for mxml components in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, mxml, thumbnails

Is it possible to make some kind of 'dynamic' thumbnails for mxml components which I'm using in my application? By 'dynamic' I mean if I change some layout in mxml component, my thumbnail refreshes according to new layout without any screen capturing, photoshoping or similar =)

*Edit:*
I am using a [FlexBook](http://www.quietlyscheming.com/blog/components/flexbook/) component, which makes a 'book' of mxml components (because each page has many independent interactions). I think that problem could be that bitmap data does not exist until I actually start to turn pages. But I would like to get bitmap data on creation complete.

Thanks!

---

Ok, let me try to explain little more because I see this is more complicated than I thought it will be..

I am using a [FlexBook](http://www.quietlyscheming.com/blog/components/flexbook/) component, which makes a 'book' of mxml components (because each page has many independent interactions). I think that problem could be that bitmap data does not exist until I actually start to turn pages. But I would like to get bitmap data on creation complete...

Thanks for help!
m.

Comment: You mean it is the thumbnail of the application? And you want the thumbnail to be BitmapData or what?

Comment: Hmmm... Well, application? They are mxml files and I use them as components in my main application. I need a thumbnail of each component I use... I suppose that BitmapData would be cool, yes =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function I coded long time ago. It takes a `DisplayObject`(mxml components are `DisplayObject` too), it will return a `Bitmap` of it.

You may write a handler to listen for `Event.RENDER` of the mxml component to update the `Bitmap` when the component is changed.

Another thing you can try on the FlexBook component is to set `creationPolicy="all"`...

```
/**
 * This function returns a Bitmap that have the same look of a given DisplayObject.
 * Ref.: http://qops.blogspot.com/2008/05/bitmap.html
 * @author Andy Li andy@onthewings.net
 * @version 20080529
 */
package net.onthewings{
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.geom.Matrix;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.PixelSnapping;
    import flash.display.Stage;

    public function bitmapEquivalentOf(obj:DisplayObject, extendsRectSidesBy:Number = 0, clipOutside = null,alpha:Boolean = true):Bitmap {
        if (obj.width && obj.height) {
            var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(obj.width, obj.height, alpha, 0xFFFFFF);
            var rect:Rectangle = obj.getBounds(obj);
            var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix;
            matrix.translate(-rect.x, -rect.y);
            bitmapData.draw(obj, matrix);
            var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData, PixelSnapping.AUTO, true);
            bitmap.x = rect.x;
            bitmap.y = rect.y;
            var ebd:BitmapData;

            if (clipOutside) {
                var h:Number;
                var w:Number;
                if (clipOutside is Stage) {
                    h = clipOutside.stageHeight;
                    w = clipOutside.stageWidth;
                } else {
                    h = clipOutside.height;
                    w = clipOutside.width;
                }
                if(!(h && w)){
                    return null;
                }
                var pt:Point = obj.localToGlobal(new Point(rect.x,rect.y));
                ebd = new BitmapData(w, h, true, 0xFFFFFF);
                ebd.copyPixels(bitmap.bitmapData,new Rectangle(-pt.x,-pt.y,w,h),new Point(0,0));
                bitmap =  new Bitmap(ebd, PixelSnapping.AUTO, true);
            } else if (extendsRectSidesBy) {
                ebd = new BitmapData(bitmapData.width+extendsRectSidesBy*2, bitmapData.height+extendsRectSidesBy*2, true, 0xFFFFFF);
                ebd.copyPixels(bitmap.bitmapData,bitmap.bitmapData.rect,new Point(extendsRectSidesBy,extendsRectSidesBy));
                bitmap =  new Bitmap(ebd, PixelSnapping.AUTO, true);
                bitmap.x = rect.x - extendsRectSidesBy;
                bitmap.y = rect.y - extendsRectSidesBy;
            }
            return bitmap;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've just found out that there is `ImageSnapshot` class in Flex which should be better that my old function. Use its `captureBitmapData` function :)

Comment: Hey hello and thanks for this great help! I was playing around with BitmapData and ImageSnapshot classes but I still cannot get thumbnails for pages in my book... I can successfully make a thumbnail for first page (which is immediately rendered), but I was not so much successful with other 'unrendered' pages... Anyway, thank you one more time!